# Why does hardware acceleration prevent GIF animation in WebView?

Tags: android, animation, webview, gif

I am developing an application, which is based on a central WebView. The WebView is used to display a large picture, which required zooming and scrolling. Additionally, I would like to place several animated objects (based on user interaction with the app). I have successfully managed to do so, thanks to [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.cz/2014/03/play-animated-gif-with.html).

However, at the end of the tutorial, there is an interesting remark - hardware acceleration needs to be turned off. Indeed, when I kept HA turned on, the gif didn't even show up. When I turned hardware acceleration off, the gif played perfectly.

Could anybody explain what is causing this behaviour? Shouldn't hardware acceleration "help" in displaying of graphics and animation?

Comment: I have the same issue using koral--/android-gif-drawable frog github. It is very unclear why it should be a problem.